# Creating SVG path in Grid points

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, d3.js

I need to create a SVG path along the green (Allowed) points to the closest point on mousedown event.

**[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wu5h6d74/)**

**The code:**

```js
var GridArea = $('#Grid');
var MapPoints;
var PointsY = 140;                
for (i = 160 ; i <= 560; i+=20) {
  if (i == 560) {
    PointsY+=20;
    i = 160;
  }
  if (PointsY >= 440){
    break;
  }
  MapPoints += ('<rect class="MapPoints NotAllowed" x="'+i+'" y="'+PointsY+'"/>');
}
GridArea.html(MapPoints + '<circle id="CirclePoint" cx="160" cy="280" r="5" fill="red"/>');
var RectGrid = $("rect");
var XValue, YValue;
var X = [160,180,200,220,240,240,240,240,260,260,260,280,300,300,320,340,360,380,400,400,380,380,380,380,380,400,420,420,420,440,440,460,480,480,500,500,520,540,420,440,460,480,500,500,520,540];
var Y = [280,300,320,320,320,340,360,380,400,320,300,300,300,280,280,280,280,280,300,280,260,240,220,200,180,160,140,320,340,340,360,380,380,400,400,420,440,440,300,300,300,300,300,280,280,260];
for (i = 0; i < RectGrid.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < X.length; j++) {
    if ($("rect:nth-child("+i+")").attr('x') == X[j] && $("rect:nth-child("+i+")").attr('y') == Y[j]) {
      $("rect:nth-child("+i+")").removeClass("NotAllowed");
      $("rect:nth-child("+i+")").addClass("Allowed");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Grid {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.MapPoints {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
  stroke: #000;
}
.NotAllowed {
  fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.40);
}
.Allowed {
  fill: rgba(0, 255, 130, 0.40);
}
.CirclePoint {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.5.0"></script>
<svg id="Grid">

</svg>
```

I need the path either crossing or going inside the "Allowed" points.
I tried to get the closest point and its worked for "X" but not for "Y", and I couldn't even draw that wrong path.

Comment: Sounds like a fairly basic pathfinding problem. Plenty of tutorials on that subject.